# Primefaces selectBooleanCheckbox value lost on ajax action

Tags: ajax, primefaces, jsf-2

Im posting MCVE here because i am confused with JSF behaviour.
I have index.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="entityForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" styleClass="entityForm">
<p:dataTable id="dataTableId1" value="#{testBean.testEntityList}" var="tent" rowKey="#{tent.id}">
    <p:column style="width:16px">
        <p:rowToggler/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{tent.id}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{tent.name}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:rowExpansion>
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{tent.something}"/>
        <p:inputText value="#{tent.strNextToSomethingCheckBox}" />
    </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
<p:commandButton id="button1" ajax="true" value="Do something" update="entityForm"/>
</h:form>
```

bean code:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "testBean")
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TestBean.class);

private List<TestEntity> testEntityList;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    LOG.debug("init call");
    testEntityList = new ArrayList<>();

    testEntityList.add(new TestEntity(1L, "Entry 1", true, "Value 1 str"));
    testEntityList.add(new TestEntity(2L, "Entry 2", false, "Value 2 str"));
    testEntityList.add(new TestEntity(3L, "Entry 3", false, "Value 3 str"));

}

public class TestEntity {

    Long id;

    String name;

    Boolean something;

    String strNextToSomethingCheckBox;


    public TestEntity(Long id, String name, Boolean something, String strNextToSomethingCheckBox) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.something = something;
        this.strNextToSomethingCheckBox = strNextToSomethingCheckBox;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Boolean getSomething() {
        return something;
    }

    public void setSomething(Boolean something) {
        LOG.debug("setSomething call");
        this.something = something;
    }

    public String getStrNextToSomethingCheckBox() {
        return strNextToSomethingCheckBox;
    }

    public void setStrNextToSomethingCheckBox(String strNextToSomethingCheckBox) {
        LOG.debug("setStrNextToSomethingCheckBox call");
        this.strNextToSomethingCheckBox = strNextToSomethingCheckBox;
    }
}


public List<TestEntity> getTestEntityList() {
    return testEntityList;
}

public void setTestEntityList(List<TestEntity> testEntityList) {
    this.testEntityList = testEntityList;
}

}
```

Scenario: when you open page, expand first row, you will see checkbox state as checked, when you press button, form is updated and checkbox is still checked (you need to expand row again to see that)

Problematic scenario: open page, do not expand any row, just click button, after form is updated, expand first row and you will see that value is set from true to false

Question: Why is value is set from true to false? Is this bug or expected behaviour ? How can i avoid this ?
Thanks.

Comment: What if you remove this: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from the `h:form`?

Comment: @Kukeltje same, value is lost / reset to false

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to primefaces `SelectBooleanCheckboxRenderer#decode` codes below:

```
@Override
public void decode(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
    SelectBooleanCheckbox checkbox = (SelectBooleanCheckbox) component;

    if(checkbox.isDisabled()) {
        return;
    }

    decodeBehaviors(context, checkbox);

    String clientId = checkbox.getClientId(context);
    String submittedValue = (String) context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(clientId + "_input");

    if(submittedValue != null && isChecked(submittedValue)) {
        checkbox.setSubmittedValue(true);
    }
    else {
        checkbox.setSubmittedValue(false);
    }
}
```

The reason why the value is set from true to false is because `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` is not set in the `RequestParameterMap` when p:rowExpansion is close. So when the `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` is decoded, `submittedValue` becomes null. Thus, executing `checkbox.setSubmittedValue(false)`.

When `p:rowExpansion` is expanded you can see the value of `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` is in `RequestParameterMap`.
You can confirm this by adding `action="#{testBean.doSomething}"` to `p:commandButton` with the follow method in the bean:

```
public void doSomething() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, String> requestParameterMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    Set<String> keySet = requestParameterMap.keySet();

    for (String key : keySet) {
        LOG.debug("key>>" + key);
        LOG.debug("value>>" + requestParameterMap.get(key));
    }
}
```

Note that `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` is also **NOT** set in the `RequestParameterMap` when it is unchecked.

<s>You can avoid this problem by overiding `SelectBooleanCheckboxRenderer#decode` and chaging this:</s>

```
if(submittedValue != null && isChecked(submittedValue)) {
    checkbox.setSubmittedValue(true);
}
else {
    checkbox.setSubmittedValue(false);
}
```

to this:

```
if (submittedValue != null && isChecked(submittedValue)) {
    checkbox.setSubmittedValue(true);
} else {
    if (checkbox.isRendered()) {
        checkbox.setSubmittedValue(false);
    }
}
```

This way the value will be false only when `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` is unchecked and is rendered.

**EDIT:**

I'm sorry. My override solution is incorrect <s>but the idea is you need to override `SelectBooleanCheckboxRenderer#decode`</s>.

I will post the correct codes when it is available.

**EDIT 2:**

Can't seem to make it work by overriding `SelectBooleanCheckboxRenderer#decode` so i tried a different approach.

I added a flag (toggled) in TestEntity with an init value of false.
This will be used as a flag to render `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` inside `p:rowExpansion`.
This flag will be set to true when the row is toggled(VISIBLE) using `p:ajax event="rowToggle"` and `onRowToggle` method in the bean.

The idea is that `SelectBooleanCheckboxRenderer#decode` will not be executed when the `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` is not rendered.
This will cause the value to be retained. This approach does **NOT** require overriding `SelectBooleanCheckboxRenderer#decode`.

Here are the codes:

**xhtml:**

```
<h:form id="entityForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" styleClass="entityForm">
<p:dataTable id="dataTableId1" value="#{testBean.testEntityList}" var="tent" rowKey="#{tent.id}">

    <p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{testBean.onRowToggle}"/>

    <p:column style="width:16px">
        <p:rowToggler/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{tent.id}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{tent.name}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:rowExpansion>
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{tent.something}" rendered="#{tent.toggled}"/>
        <p:inputText value="#{tent.strNextToSomethingCheckBox}" />
    </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
<p:commandButton id="button1" ajax="true" value="Do something" update="entityForm"/>
</h:form>
```

**bean:**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "testBean")
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TestBean.class);

    private List<TestEntity> testEntityList;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        LOG.debug("init call");
        testEntityList = new ArrayList<>();

        testEntityList.add(new TestEntity(1L, "Entry 1", true, "Value 1 str", false));
        testEntityList.add(new TestEntity(2L, "Entry 2", false, "Value 2 str", false));
        testEntityList.add(new TestEntity(3L, "Entry 3", false, "Value 3 str", false));
    }

    public class TestEntity {

        Long id;

        String name;

        Boolean something;

        String strNextToSomethingCheckBox;

        boolean toggled;

        public TestEntity(Long id, String name, Boolean something, String strNextToSomethingCheckBox, boolean toggled) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.something = something;
            this.strNextToSomethingCheckBox = strNextToSomethingCheckBox;
            this.toggled = toggled;
        }

        // getters and setters
    }

    public List<TestEntity> getTestEntityList() {
        return testEntityList;
    }

    public void setTestEntityList(List<TestEntity> testEntityList) {
        this.testEntityList = testEntityList;
    }

    public void onRowToggle(ToggleEvent event) {
        TestEntity entity = (TestEntity) event.getData();

        if (event.getVisibility() == Visibility.VISIBLE) {
            entity.setToggled(true);
        } else {
            entity.setToggled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.